# How to have the results of an `fzf` selection enter my bash history?

Tags: bash, command-history, fzf

FZF is a lovely tool, the main issue I have is that the commands I end up running with it don't end up in my bash history.

Let's say I do this

```
history | fzf
```

And I choose a command I ran recently, say `echo "hello"`.  When I then go through my bash history, my most recently run command isn't `echo "hello"`, it's `history | fzf`. This means that I have to re-run the entire `history | fzf` and find the same `echo "hello"` command if I want to run it again.

Is there a way to force my selected command that I got by using `fzf` into my bash history?

Comment: Does using `Ctrl+r` not do this already? In mine `Ctrl+r` launches fzf on my history, and pressing enter on some old item pastes it to the terminal - if I run that command by pressing enter, then it shows up as the last item in the history

Comment: That is because you have not executed the hello command. You have merely  printed that hello command out in your terminal. Your last executed command is history | fzf which shows in your history.